# Statistical analysis of fourier transform of a 2D image (freaking AMAZING)

Tags: contingency-tables, signal-processing, fourier-transform, signal-detection

I'm a statistics grad student, and I **just** started getting into Digital-Image-Processing (an analogy for processing super-large contingency tables).  In the book "**Digital Image Processing**" by Gonzalez and Woods, I was reading chapter 2, page 94 of the third edition, and found the following image that is MAGIC to me...

[image: Removing Sinusoidal interference - DIP Gonzalez Woods]

They begin with a noisy image, identify some 'hot points' surrounding the center of the Fourier transform, then simply remove them, reverse the transform, and ***POW!***  Magically the image is crystal clear!!!

Does anyone have any insite into this?  Are there any statistical approaches that can be used to test a hypothesis that these 'hot points' are in fact interference?  Are there *other* interesting approaches to analyzing these transforms statistically??

If any of the StackExchange users a familiar with this topic and can suggest some articles/books that I might read, I would be very grateful. And to anyone who is NOT familiar with this topic... HOW AWESOME IS THIS?!?!?

Comment: You might want to ask this question on https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/ for a possible set of code to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Random noise tends to turn into high frequency Fourier coefficients.  FFT.  Clip the high frequencies off.  IFT.  Cleaner picture...unless what you are seeking resides in the noise.  This is true for 1D and 2D.

Old, standard technique...too often forgotten about in favor of smoothers and wavelets.